# Как получить отображение вставленных данных(insert) на исходную таблицу?

Tags: sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы (гипотетические)

```
TableSource(id int IDENTITY(1,1), value int, order int) 

TableTarget(id int IDENTITY(1,1), value)
```

И операция вставки данных из первой во вторую

```
INSERT TableTarget(value)
SELECT s.value 
FROM TableSource s
WHERE order < 10
```

Мне нужно как-то получить отображение id записей из TableSource на новые вставленные строки в TableTarget.

```
IdTableSource | idTableTarget
-----------------------------
2             | 1
4             | 2
5             | 3
7             | 4
9             | 5
```

Возможно есть какой то способ добавить эти данные в OUTPUT, но не нашёл как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> способ добавить эти данные в OUTPUT

`INSERT` не позволяет направлять в `OUTPUT` любые столбцы из источника (лишь те, которые доступны в `inserted`). Это возможно только помощью `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO TableTarget T
USING (
    SELECT id, value
    FROM TableSource
    WHERE [order] < 10
) S
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (value)
    VALUES (S.value)
OUTPUT S.id AS idSource, inserted.id AS idTarget;
```

Comment: не только, пример привел